# Splash image appears as icon in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, splash-screen

I have a weird issue, which many of you might not even have thought of!

An application I developed, works fine on both iPhone and iPad, but the icon appears perfectly fine on iPhone, whereas on the iPad, the splash image scales down and shows up as icon.

I'm not sure what's going on. I tried checking on and off Prerendered flag, but no use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the launch image?

Comment: Delete your app from simulator then Clean & build it again.

Comment: Am sorry, yes, its the launch image @DummyCode

Comment: Yea, did that, but didn't work. @raaz

Comment: Maybe take a screenshot of the setting for icons and default images of your project. Are there any warnings indicated there?

Comment: Is it a simulator issue, or a device, or both?

Comment: For iPad you need to add seperate icons: 77 x 77 and 144 x 144 (for iPhone it is 57 x 57 and 114 x 114) Did you add the iPad icons files?